# Firebase - Structuring Data For Efficient Indexing

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I've read almost everywhere about structuring one's `Firebase Database` for efficient querying, but I am still a little confused between two alternatives that I have.

For example, let's say I want to get all of a user's "maxBenchPressSessions" from the past 7 days or so.

I'm stuck between picking between these two structures:

[image]

In the first array, I use the user's id as an attribute to index on whether true or false. In the second, I use `userId` as the attribute NAME whose value would be the user's id.

Is one faster than the other, or would they be indexed a relatively same manner? I kind of new to database design, so I want to make sure that I'm following correct practices.

***PROGRESS***

I have come up with a solution that will both flatten my database AND allow me to add a `ListenerForSingleValueEvent` using `orderBy` ONLY once, but only when I want to check if a user has a session saved for a specific day.

[image]

I can have each `maxBenchPressSession` object have a key in the format of `userId_dateString`. However, if I want to get all the user's sessions from the last 7 days, I don't know how to do it in one query.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no data structure that is inherently faster or slower. The difference depends on how you access the data from your code. If you show the queries that you want to write, it'll be easier to help. In general: model the data for how your app accesses it. See this article about [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: I would use a single value event listener just to make one query. I would get all `maxBenchPressSessions` from a user from the past 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to watch the video. It is told about the structuring of the data very well.

[References to the playlist on the firebase 3](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdssc-pDiZ7OD78kJVp4habTynj-Etwhm)

[Firebase 3.0: Data Modelling](https://youtu.be/9gnvC-xIDgs?list=PLdssc-pDiZ7OD78kJVp4habTynj-Etwhm)

[Firebase 3.0: Node Client](https://youtu.be/G_FlX41qADE?list=PLdssc-pDiZ7OD78kJVp4habTynj-Etwhm)

Comment: I see the part in the video where he uses "username" as a key and the user's username as the value, but this contradicts the Firebase docs when they use a user's username as a key and a boolean as a value.

Comment: My question is more of whether either is more efficient or if those methods are the same. By the way, I'm not trying to stream the data. I'm simply setting up a single value event listener just to get the data once.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the principle firebase to use it effectively. Should be as small as possible to query the data and it does not matter how many requests.

But you will approach such a request. We'll have to add another field to the database "negativeDate".

This field allows you to get the last seven entries. Here's a video -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMR_JPfL4qg&feature=youtu.be&t=4m36s

[image]

```
.limitToLast(7) - 7 entries
.orderByChild('negativeDate') - sort by date
```

Example of a request:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('maxBenchPressSession');
ref.orderByChild('negativeDate').limitToLast(7).on('value', function(snap){ })
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I need, but this only gives me all sessions from the past 7 days, regardless of user. I need to get all of the user's sessions from the past seven days.

Answer (score 0):

Then add the user, and it puts all of its sessions.

[image]

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('maxBenchPressSession/' + userId);
ref.orderByChild('negativeDate').limitToLast(7).on('value', function(snap){ })
```